# Django template: string automatically got truncated by white space in input value

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to set the initial value of a input field. In the template, I have

```
<input id="title" name="title" value={{ post_title }}>
```

where `post_title` is a string. The weird thing is, if there is a whitespace in `post_title`, it would be split and only the part before the whitespace would be displayed. For example, if `post_title = "hello world"`, the rendered html is

```
<input id="title" name="title" value="hello" world>
```

Everything is ok without whitespaces in `post_title`. I'm using Django 1.3.1 and python 2.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django's template engine won't fix broken HTML.

```
<input id="title" name="title" value="{{ post_title }}">
```